# Why is data getting whitened in seaborn pairplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The following code reads data from a csv file.

Afterwards with `supplyHue()` discrete values are assigned to column `c` according to the value ranges of column `a`. For the distribution of the numerical values of `a` the hist plot in the pairplot below might be helpful.

So what `supplyHue()` basically does: put the data of column `a` into bins so that they can be assigned to different colors / hue values for the plot.

Lateron the seaborn pairplot is done.

Depending how much I zoom out of the plot, the colors at the left side of plot get "whitened" out: instead of a solid pink color the canvas gets ***very bright***, the more data points get plotted over each other. This is also strange, as the same color should be true for a certain value of `a` for all values of `b` (displacement along the y axis).

If I zoom in, this effect disappears almost completely.

**What can I do that this brightening of the color does not happen?**

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r"https://pastebin.com/raw/7ez3WQzW")

def supplyHue(x):
    if x < 1:
        myReturn = 1
    elif x < 2:
        myReturn = 2
    elif x < 4:
        myReturn = 4
    elif x < 6:
        myReturn = 6
    elif x < 10:
        myReturn = 10
    elif x < 15:
        myReturn = 15
    elif x < 18:
        myReturn = 18
    else:
        myReturn = 20
    return myReturn

df['c'] = df.a.apply(lambda x: supplyHue(x))

g = sns.pairplot(
    df,
    corner=True,
    vars=['a', 'b'],
    plot_kws=dict(
        hue=df['c'],
    ),
)
g.add_legend()
g.axes[1][0].grid()
plt.show()
```

Zoomed out:

[image: whitened out]

Zoomed in - it's more or less ok:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `edgecolor` of the markers, pass `edgecolor='None'` to the subplot

```
g = sns.pairplot(
    df,
    corner=True,
    vars=['a', 'b'],
    plot_kws=dict(
        hue=df['c'],
        edgecolor='None',
    ),
)
```

before:

[image: original]

after:

[image: no edgecolor]

Comment: Not sure of the exact color, and I think it is set by seaborn because of the numerical hue. Has this solved your issue?